# Converting a UK mapping application from Ordnance Survey OpenSpace API to OS Maps API

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers

I am in the process of converting my browser based mapping applications from OpenSpace API to OS Maps API. I am using JavaScript.

For a while I’ve had a hybrid system using both API libraries and now wish to eliminate the residual OpenSpace calls.

The on-line conversion guidance from OpenSpace to OS Maps is rather limited and doesn’t tell me how to convert between coordinate systems (Lat/Long to British National Grid and vice versa) which OpenSpace does via a built-in GridProjection function.

For example how would I achieve the following in OS Maps without the GridProjection call?

```
var gridprojection = new OpenSpace.GridProjection(); // set-up a grid projection

var pt = osMap.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(e.xy); // get a clicked (BNG) point on a map

var lonlat = gridprojection.getLonLatFromMapPoint(pt); // use gridprojection to convert BNG to lat/long
```

And:

```
var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(long,lat); // create a lat/long point

var os = gridprojection.getMapPointFromLonLat(lonlat); // use gridprojection to convert lat/long to BNG
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OpenLayers 2 you will need to include the proj4js version 1 library

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/1.1.0/proj4js-combined.min.js"></script>
```

Then add a definition for the BNG projection EPSG:27700

```
Proj4js.defs["EPSG:27700"] = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs ";
```

Then you can use the transform method on LonLat objects to convert to and from the lon/lat projection EPSG:4326 and BNG

```
new OpenLayers.LonLat(long, lat).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:27700"))
```